# Unable to delete the data from grid view even the jquery returns true

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have used the following script to check whether an item is selected from grid view or not which works fine. When I am showing a confirm box and if the user selects OK I am returning to `true` if not `False`. But on `Ok` I am unable to delete the selected item from the grid view can any one help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").click(function () {
            var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdPayroll.ClientID%>");
            var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var flag = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                if (rbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    if (rbs[i].checked) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');
            }
            else {
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").click(function () {
                    var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdPayroll.ClientID%>");
                    var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    var flag = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
                        if (rbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                            if (rbs[i].checked) {
                                flag = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        jAlert('Select One', 'Alert Dialog');
                        //return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
                            if (r == true)
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                        });
                        //return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sample code under button

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int EmpID = 0;
    int chkRows = 0;
    string strWageID = string.Empty;
    int Payperiodnumber = 0;
    int PayYear = 0;
    DateTime dtPaymentdate;
    string strFedTaxID = string.Empty;
    strFedTaxID = ddlFedTaxID.SelectedValue;

    if (rdSimul.Checked == true)
    {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that `<%=grdPayroll.ClientID%>` is really the name of the object you want to delete ? Have inspected the page via firebug and looked if this element exists on the page ? Also why dont you use $('#something') to get the element instead of document.getElementbyID ?

Comment: Yes the name of the object is the same as I given

Comment: How can i `$('#something') ` use this instead of `document.getElementbyID `

Comment: the same way you did it with $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete")

Comment: You means as this `document.getElementById("#ContentPlaceHolder1_grdPayroll");`

Comment: I think you should take a look at Selectory from jQuery. Seriously there's no way the code you provided can be done by you, if you have no clue about that.

Comment: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/ this one I modified as per my need

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the statement to delete the selected row from the grid ?  sorry if it sounded stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the element from the DOM?

```
$('#<%=grdPayroll.ClientID%>').remove();
```

Comment: Not removing the element from DOM I have written separate code for that in my code on Button click